# I am having problems printing my struct (with names and phone numbers read from a file). How do I fix it?

Tags: c

```
typedef struct Data {
    int name;
    int surname;
    int phone;
} Data;

char buf[50];

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("src.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("The file is empty or doesnt exist.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file);
    Data dat[100];
    int i;
    while (!feof(file)) {
        Data *d = dat + i;
        sscanf(buf, "%d %d %d", &dat->name, &dat->surname, &dat->phone);
        fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), file);
        i++;
    }
    int n = i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Name: %d\nSurname: %d\nPhone: %d\n", dat[i].name, dat[i].surname, 
        dat[i].phone);
    }
    fclose(file);
    exit(0);
}
```

I am trying to read lines of a file into a struct and then print the struct.
the file looks like this:

```
Name Surname Phonenumber
Heinz Friedrich 015134532525
Amy Albertson 015443246678
```

When I try to print the struct it just shows me random numbers. I also tried to use chars but then it just says `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.

Comment: `int name` and `int surname`? Shouldn't those be strings?

Comment: You should check the return value of `sscanf()`. It will tell you that the input isn't numbers, so the `%d` format couldn't parse it.

Comment: You should edit your question and provide a sample from the input file.

Comment: [Enable your warnings and read them](https://godbolt.org/z/9e6Efjazr). You probably meant to use that `d` variable. [Here's how and why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings).

Answer (score 2):

There are two main issues:

First, you do not initialize variable `i`, such that `Data *d = dat + i` will yield undefined behaviour; use `int i = 0` instead of `int i;`

Second, you read data format integers where the file provides strings, actually. Use `%s` instead of `%d`, in `scanf` as well as in `printf`.

Comment: I tried this before and it doesnt work. It gives me an error because in printf `dat[i].name` is an int and I dont know how to fix that

Comment: `char name[50]` instead of `int name`, for example.

Comment: now it says that `dat[i].name` is `char (*) [50]` and `%s` doesnt work because its `char *`

Comment: `char name[50]`, not `char *name[50]`